# Confused on why this command isn't working

Tags: python, discord, command

My commands aren't really working and anything else I try such as `on_message` doesn't work either. I am kind of new to this.

```
from discord.ext import commands 
import discord
import math
import random as r
from discord import message
from discord.colour import Color



token = ''

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = '%')

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print("Goldie is ready to run. Logged into {0.user}".format(discord.Client()))

@client.command()
async def helpm(ctx):
    embed = discord.Embed(
    title="Help System", color = discord.colour.Color.gold(),description=" Need some help?\n\nLook below for some commands or other support. For more information visit my website! ").set_author(name="Goldie Support",icon_url='https://ih1.redbubble.net/image.2049235988.9593/st,small,507x507-pad,600x600,f8f8f8.jpg') 
    embed.add_field(name="Commands", value="%help\n%website", inline=True) 
    embed.add_field(name="Math", value="`%add(Number 1) (Number 2)`\n%subtract(Number 1) (Number 2)\n%multiply (Number 1) (Number 2)\n%divide (Number 1) (Number 2)\n%remainder (Number 1) (Number 2)\n%random (Parameter 1) (Parameter 2)", inline=True) 
    embed.add_field(name="Support", value="My website - link", inline=True) 
    await ctx.send(embed=embed)
      
client.run(token)
```

I've seen a lot of online stuff and searched about it, and hasn't worked. Don't know if I'm doing it completely wrong or what.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the code you provided. Your bot lacks intents. Your bot should work as intended if you make the following changes:

```py
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = '%', intents=discord.Intents.all())

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print("Goldie is ready to run. Logged into {0.user}".format(discord.Client(intents=discord.Intents.all())))
```

Make sure all options under Privileged Gateway Intents are checked for your Bot in the Discord Developer Portal as shown
[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qu92R.png)